# Running Python Selenium script on raspberry pi auto start

Tags: python, selenium, automation, raspberry-pi

i have a big problem with running selenium script which opens chromium browser and shows some dashboards in Tableau from auto start. I am using raspberry pi 4  with newest Raspbian from their webpage.

When performing script manually, everything works fine and as should. I tried tips from several posts for ex. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41305/selenium-script-on-startup
So i tried various things with my cronos setups: dealays on script run, setting up screen etc. Still nothing helps.

Logger from cronos returns me error like this:

```
/home/pi/Documents/test.py:22: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/test.py", line 22, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 270, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 363, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 428, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Normally when working good it should stop on and starting to perform Selenium tasks in newly opened chromium browser:

```
/home/pi/Documents/test.py:22: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(
```

Right now after many tries my cronos file looks like:

```
@reboot sleep 60; env -i DISPLAY=:0.0 python /home/pi/Documents/test.py  > /home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

Hope that anybody could help me, i am struggling with this problem from many hours and tried various and many solutions but nothhins seems working.

Answer (score 0):

For Selenium or any GUI application on startup, I would recommend using the pi's built in Autostart system:

Create the desktop file:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/test.desktop
```

Enter the following details:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Test
Exec=python /home/pi/Documents/test.py
Terminal=true
x-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=60
```

Change the file permissions for good measure:

```
chmod 777 /home/pi/Documents/test.py
```

Finally, reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

ref: https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-run-a-raspberry-pi-program-script-at-startup/